# Error double [,] to image

Tags: c#, image

I am trying to use this example (see first answer):
[C# convert a 2D double array to and greyscale image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067748/c-sharp-convert-a-2d-double-array-to-and-greyscale-image)
I am getting this error:
https://i.imgsafe.org/2226c81bdc.png

I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Without seeing your code how can we help you? Please show code in your question, screenshots of code are not helpful.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049240/obtaining-the-min-and-max-of-a-two-dimensional-array-using-linq

Comment: Also see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15395139/5095502). The example you are using is incomplete, that person must be using an extension method such as the one I just linked, or they typed the code without actually testing it.

Comment: try this.. double min = data.Cast<double>().Min();

Comment: Thank you, double min = data.Cast<double>().Min(); worked!

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be that the user who answered the question created an extension method similar to this:

```
public static double Min(this double[,] values)
{
    double min = double.MaxValue;

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (value < min)
        {
            min = value;
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

Plus a similar method for Max()

**EDIT:** The foreach loop could also be replaced with the
    data.Cast().Min()
call as suggested by @JerryGoyal